# Publish webcam feed to Flash Media Server

Tags: flash, red5, rtmp, h.264, flash-media-server

I have a fairly high-end webcam (snc-rz25n) that I need to rebroadcast using the Flash Media Server. I can get the picture as MPEG-4 (not h.264). So I need to transcode to h.264 and publish at multiple bitrates to FMS.

The only solution I have been able to come up with thus far is to transcode the stream using ffmpeg and then also use ffmpeg to downconvert the stream (for the multiple bitrates) and then publish all of these transcoded streams to FMS via custom Java code (using Red5).

Surely there is a better way. Flash Live Media Encoder is not going to work. The camera is on the network, not direct connected, and I need a linux solution.

Comment: H.264 is a part of the MPEG-4 standard (H.264/AVC/MPEG-4 Part 10). What are you getting the picture as, if not H.264? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H264

Comment: Yes, H.264 is part of the MPEG-4 standard, but not all MPEG-4 is H.264. I believe the input format is MPEG-4 part 2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4

Comment: *"Surely there is a better way."*  What you have done looks sane to me.  What exactly don't you like about it?

Comment: Hi, Jonathan would you share code snippet of custom java code, becoz I am also looking similar solution.  I want stop using FlashMediEncoder instead use xuggler/ffmpeg with Red5 java api.

Comment: http://old.nabble.com/RTMP-java-Client-for-video-publishing-td20939125.html

Comment: hello Jonathan, actually I am looking for a RTMPClient encoder java application, sample code. The encoder java application should publish the webcam feed to Red5 server.  We are able to do this with flash action script but could not find proper samples in java. please share custom java code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have found the best solution until FMS supports live transcoding. I know that Wowza (FMS competitor) is planning on a feature similar to this for Q4 20111.